# Application wizard in Prism 4

Tags: c#, prism

I would like to make a wizard in my application. Where can I find an example of create the wizard?

I mean it http://www.tenouk.com/clabworksheet/labworksheet3_files/win32consoleapp006.png (Previos, Next, Finish )

Answer (score 2):

Try [the Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) which added a new Wizard Control in its latest release.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I thought may be to use Prism navigation API to create a wizard, maybe someone knows how to do it.

Comment: You're welcome. I believe that doing it with Prism is possible, of course, but it would be way more complex than using an existing control ;)